# C# - Foreach Url in Listbox, complete tasks

Tags: c#, foreach, listbox, wait

So in my program I have a button that calls a function. Let's call it GotoWebsite(). I also have a listbox that has all of the Url's that we'll be going to. Each site needs to fully load as there are various tasks that need to be completed at each page.

ie:
GotoWebsite(Url1) -> Navigate to Url1. Login to page. Post a message.
->Go to next Website and follow similar procedures.

I have tried foreach loops, Queue's, using DocumentCompleted at the final page of each Url, etc. Nothing I try seems to work.

The end result is always the same: The last item on the list is executed successfully most times; the rest were rushed through and basically skipped because it went too fast.

Anyone know a way I can make my GotoWebsite() function fully trigger with each Url in a listbox / string array / string list?

I know I haven't shown any of my actual code, unfortunately I'm not home at the moment. This is a poor representation of what I'm trying to do, though:

```
private void button1.click()
{
    foreach (string url in listbox1)
        {
            GotoWebsite()
        }
}

private void GotoWebsite()
{
    //Send POST data to login
    //search page for data
    //POST more information
}

//Continue the previous loop now that GotoWebsite() is complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would iterate your listbox calling GoToWebsite();

```
listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ForEach((s) => GoToWebSite(s));
```

I can not understand well exactly what you are requesting but inside GotoWebsite
is going to be your login (Post data), so you can manage if the call was succesful
or it was not.

Comment: That's awesome, pretty much exactly what I'm looking for... THANKS!  Also.. similar question to my original... say I have a listbox of e-mail addresses and each one needs to be carried to a function, and set to a string, say s. (so, for first Mail() s = email1 from the list, second Mail() s = email2 from the list etc).. how could I do that?

Comment: listBox1Email.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ForEach((s) => ProcessMail(s)); and the create a function void ProcessMail (string email).

Comment: Thanks Carlos! Definitely helped a lot.. One more question, though. With that iteration in your first response, won't it still try to go too quickly without waiting for GoToWebsite() to complete before moving to the next listbox index?

Comment: I'm using a webbrowser not HTTPWebRequest so it's a bit slower than it should be and is why I need it to wait for a completed GoToWebsite() task.

Comment: Yes, that was What I was gonna suggest, use a Task.Wait

Comment: not sure how to use Task.Wait, really. Can you point me to an example? I really appreciate all your assistance.